# How do I make my last navigation link a different colour using css nth child

Tags: html, css

I seem to not be able to make the JOIN link in my navigation bar the colour gold (#ba9a45) using css nth child or by using the alternative class "join" and adding a value of gold (#ba9a45).

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CASINO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MEMBERS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="join">JOIN</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using nth-child

```
.navbar li a:nth-last-child{
  color: #ba9a45;
}
```

Using class="join"

```
.navbar li a{
  .join{
    color: #ba9a45;
  }
}
```

How can I fix this issue using both nth-child and alternatively the class "join"?

Comment: Your <ul> is missing the class `navbar`. Also, `nth-last-child` should include a `(1)`. Finally, the last child selector should be on the <li> tag, not the <a> tag. Here: `.navbar li:nth-last-child(1) a { color: red; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by one of the following. Also make sure the relevant parent div or `<ul>` has the class of `.navbar`

```
.navbar li:last-child a {
  color: #ba9a45;
}
```

OR:

```
.navbar li a.join {
  color: #ba9a45;
}
```

and if the parent div has the class `.navbar` the correct CSS would be:

```
.navbar ul li:last-child a {
  color: #ba9a45;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add & before join class

```
.navbar li a{
  &.join{
    color: #ba9a45;
  }
}
```

Demo in css

```css
.navbar li a.join{
    color: #ba9a45;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CASINO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MEMBERS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="join">JOIN</a></li>
</ul>
```

or

Add `:last-child` in `<li>`

```
.navbar li:last-child a{
  color: #ba9a45;
}
```

Demo in css

```css
.navbar li:last-child a{
  color: #ba9a45;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CASINO</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MEMBERS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="join">JOIN</a></li>
</ul>
```